# Multi tenancy bundling minification caching issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, multi-tenant, bundling-and-minification

I'm struggling to implement the bundling and minification framework in my multi tenancy application.

For the sake of simplicity here's a little example:

The following routes are configured:

```
string mandatorConstraints = "Default|Other";
string defaultMandator = "Default";

routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.MapRoute("Content", "{mandator}/Content/{*filePath}", new { mandator = defaultMandator, controller = "Environment", action = "ContentFile" }, new { mandator = mandatorConstraints });
routes.MapRoute("Full", "{mandator}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { mandator = defaultMandator, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { mandator = mandatorConstraints });
```

The mandator reflects the connectionstring key to get the according database.

After that I'm going to (pre)register all required bundles for each tenant.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    BundleTable.VirtualPathProvider = new ThemedVirtualPathProvider(BundleTable.VirtualPathProvider);
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Content/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    foreach (string mandator in new[] { "Default", "Other" })
    {
        Bundle defaultStyles = new Bundle(string.Format("~/{0}/Content/css", mandator), new ThemableCssMinify());
        defaultStyles.Include(string.Format("~/{0}/Content/Site.css", mandator));
        defaultStyles.Include(string.Format("~/{0}/Content/custom.css", mandator));
        bundles.Add(defaultStyles);
    }
}
```

This seems to work pretty well, if you access the application with the following URL:

```
http://localhost/Routing/default the correct styles are loaded.
Even if you switch to the other tenant http://localhost/Routing/other the according css gets loaded correctly.
```

But if I'm going to change the stylesheet once it's processed (Site2.css) I'm not able to invalidate the cache. It should invalidate the cache once you browse tho the About Controller action.

Attached you'll find an example solution:[example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66056681/Example.zip)

Any ideas?

There's a discussion starting at: http://forums.asp.net/t/1952801.aspx?Multi+tenancy+bundling+minification+caching+issue

Comment: Did you use any query string parameter like `?12345` after the url of the minified CSS file rendered.